# Lo Yecheratz Kelev Lishono - What about other animals?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Rashi points out that because the dogs did not bark when the Jews left Egypt, they were rewarded with the basar neveilah.

Since they were uniquely rewarded, this implies that all the other animals did speak at yetzias mirzrayim.

The majority of the livestock were killed in the plagues.
The tzefardea all died.
The locusts were swept away.
And for the most part the wild animals fled after the plague of Arov.
There were very few animals left to make noise at that time.

It would appear that only smaller wild animals with a propensity to hang around human habitations for food and shelter would have remained after the plagues, such as racoons and squirrels, but those didn't exist in Egypt. The most notable of this group of animals is the shu'al.

**So my question is this:**

> ### [What did the Fox say?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fox_(What_Does_the_Fox_Say%3F))

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: That's great. I saw the question title earlier today but i didn't see the purim torah tag so didn't bother reading it, assuming this was a real question. Now, that there was an answer given my curiosity was piqued, so i read it, still not noticing the tag then I get to what does the Fox say:) +1

Comment: "Ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!
 Gering-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!
 Gering-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding!"

Answer (score 1):

One would have to assume the foxes did say something and were therefore punished:
as indicated in the question, the wild animals were no longer in mitzrayim after Arov. And it says in pirkei avos, hevei zanav l'arayos v'al tehi rosh l'shualim, "Be the tail of lions; do not be the head of foxes." Thus, the fate of the foxes must have been worse than that of the lions.

The pasuk says (Bamidbar 23:24): הֶן עָם כְּלָבִיא יָקוּם וְכַאֲרִי יִתְנַשָּׂא לֹא יִשְׁכַּב עַד יֹאכַל טֶרֶף, so we see the lions were "יֹאכַל טֶרֶף", i.e. got the treife meat just like the dogs. Since the foxes are worse, it follows that they do not get this reward, indicating that they did speak at yetzias mitzrayim. (It also indicates that lions did not speak at yetzias mitzrayim, which makes sense, since they were not around at the time.)

Answer (score 0):

Since the fox is a smart animal, it knows enough to keep quiet and stay out of the way when faced with the Mal'ach Hamaves. As a result, when they sensed the deaths around them, they knew enough to hide and keep silent.